# html table scroll bar covers part of last cell

Tags: html

I have a table with 3 cells across - The scroll bar covers part of the right hand cell making the 3 cells different widths AND part of the data in the right hand cells are coverd

I've tried all sorts of things including ones recommended here

Here is my code

```
<div style="padding: 15px; height: 500px;width: 775px;  overflow: auto;">

<table class="aligncenter" width = "500" style="border-width: 1px; border-color: #6b1ae4; background-color: #cfdfee;" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>cell #1a...............</td>
<td>cell #2a...............</td>
<td>cell #3a...............</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>cell #1b...............</td>
<td>cell #2b...............</td>
<td>cell #3b...............</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: `<tbody "width: 100%;">` Have you taken the time to learn the basics of HTML? A lot of questions asked are because people try to jump in the deep end.

Comment: I think I had just <tbody> but I've been going so crazy trying to fix this problem that I jump from forum to forum trying their suggestion - so far nothing works. - so should I take out the width or are you just making a comment?

Comment: I took out the width - made it 90%,100%,110%. Did nothing. So it's something else. I've been googling all over looking for a solution. @popnoodles - I realize I'm offended by your comment. I know more than the basics of HTML. I've been building webpages for 15 years but this table scrolling is something new so I googled for a scroll. I would really appreciate help instead of comments like that

Comment: I'm sorry if you're offended, however you wrote this `<tbody "width: 100%;">` That's not valid HTML. Your table has `width = "500" ` and a style attribute. What have you been doing for 15 years?? It doesn't look like you've been learning HTML for any part of it. Fair enough there may be the odd thing that you can't work out but the problem doesn't even present itself in the code you've supplied.

Comment: Now I took out the width from the tbody tag so that's not the problem unless something else belongs there . @ popnoodles - do you see the problem, or should I look somewhere else?

Comment: No The width=500 was never the problem. The inline CSS overrides that anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that worked for me

```
<div style="padding: 1px; height: 500px;width: 775px;  overflow: auto;">
<table class="aligncenter" width = "755" style="border-width: 1px; border-color: #6b1ae4; background-color: #cfdfee;" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" align="center">
```

I think making the width of the table smaller than the width of the div did it - Then I just played with the numbers to get it just right

Answer (score 0):

Is it something you are looking for:

```
<div style="padding: 15px; height: 500px;width: 775px;  overflow: auto;">

<table class="aligncenter" style="width:500px;" style="border-width: 1px; border-color: #6b1ae4; background-color: #cfdfee;" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>cell #1a...............</td>
<td>cell #2a...............</td>
<td>cell #3a...............</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>cell #1b...............</td>
<td>cell #2b...............</td>
<td>cell #3b...............</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: @Vishwas If you put two of the same tags in one element, the seconds is ignored. You mean `style="width:500px; border-width: 1px...`